# MySQL Procedure structure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure to allow users to rent a car, there are numerous tables in my DB, the ones I am using are 'car' and 'customer'. I want the user to be able to insert a car registration and their mobile number, from here, a search will be conducted from the 'car' table to see if they car registration they inputted matches any stored in the 'car' table. Here is what I have so far -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_loan 

(
IN  `@car_reg` VARCHAR(10) ,
IN  `@mobile_no` int)


BEGIN

        SELECT  carReg
          FROM car
          WHERE (carReg = car_reg);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

it brings up nothing except an empty car_reg even when the input data matches that in the car table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more consistent in your variable names.

```
`@car_reg` != car_reg
```

Something like this should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE new_loan 
(
IN  v_car_reg VARCHAR(10) ,
IN  v_mobile_no int)
BEGIN
        SELECT  carReg
          FROM car
          WHERE (carReg = v_car_reg);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```